# MySQL Get Difference of 2 Dates...1 retrieved and 1 hardcoded

Tags: mysql, datediff

sorry, it's hard to explain my question in one line.

Here's my current query in MySQL:

```
SELECT purch_id AS PURCH_ID, 
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),(purch_date)) AS PURCH_DATE 
FROM CS260USER.candy_purchase;
```

So as an example, one of the purch_date entries is 10-28-2004
What I really want to get is actually the difference between that (10-28-2004) and Christmas Day of THIS YEAR, 2012. (Yes, this is for a homework thingy, I'm not really that interested in Christmas Day, but the professor is :P )

Okay, so what I tried to do was something like this:

```
SELECT purch_id AS PURCH_ID, 
DATEDIFF('12-25-2012',(purch_date)) AS PURCH_DATE 
FROM CS260USER.candy_purchase;
```

But it didn't like that.

And the full part of the assignment is to code in the '12-25' part but then retrieve the current year, so that if you tried this again in 2013 it'd work for 12-15-2013.

Does that make sense? Need to retrieve data that's in the table, and find the difference between that and Christmas Day of the Current Year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select datediff(concat(year(now()),'-12-25'), purchase_date)
```

Comment: Hmm. How I do that? Gimme a min. Sorry bout that.

Comment: I can't up vote you since I don't have enough rep or something. But I THINK I accepted your answer now

Answer (score 0):

MySQL dates are in ISO format: `YYYY-MM-DD`

Which would be obvious if you'd do something like: `SELECT CURDATE();`